# Can I have a DataGrid Style's Content Presenter vary by column?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I've inherited the following Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MainPlanDataGridCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    ...
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MainPlanTable" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        ...
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource MainPlanDataGridCell}" />
        ...
    </Style>
```

And it's used in the control as such:

```
<DataGrid
      Grid.Row="2"
      Grid.Column="0"
      ...
      Style="{StaticResource MainPlanTable}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
                ...
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But I need to have different cell-columns have different alignments.
Is there way to accomplish this using a Style?  And if not can someone suggest the best way to accomplish this (the high-level approach)?

Comment: Thanks thatguy and Bandook; both answered got me there.  @thatguy, I didn't mentioned that I left out a boatload of the control template and that it's required for program consistency.  After using either of your approaches what I wound up doing was adding was adding TemplateBinding to the control: ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />.  Both answers got me to the same place, but I learned a a lot working through thatguy's, so I checked that answer.  I'm new at this, so if I did that wrong let me know for the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `DataGrid` with its built-in column types like `DataGridTextColumn` and want to change alignments, you do not have to change the control template, just create a style and set it as `ElementStyle` of the column.

```
<!-- Example style that centers the text block in the column -->
<Style x:Key="TextBlockColumnAlignCenterStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
   <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

The `TargetType` must match the control in the column. This is an example for `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`.

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxColumnAlignCenterStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

To apply these styles, simply assign them to the target columns in your `DataGrid`, for example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <!-- ...other code. -->
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyText}"
                          ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBlockColumnAlignCenterStyle}"/>
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding MyBoolean}"
                              ElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxColumnBackgroundStyle}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Please not that `ElementStyle` only applies to non-edit mode of a data grid cell. If you need to change alignments or other properties in edit mode, you have to create styles for `EditingElementStyle`, too.

If you would need to have custom controls in your column, you would use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and create a custom `DataTemplate`, but for simple data like text, this is unnecessary, use the built-in columns instead.

Answer (score 0):

I created something like that for a prototype application, you can extract the styles if possible. Otherwise use it as such,

```
<DatGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnHeader1" Width="Auto">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}" //your alignment & other styles here />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnHeader2" Width="Auto">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding somethingElse}" //your alignment & other styles here />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

You can control whether the cell is a TexBlock or TextBox or any other control. Perhaps make a style for each textbox/textblock and put it as staticresource within that xaml tag.

Note: if doing it this way, you'll need to set `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">`

Comment: I wound up needing to change the header too, so your style helped me get there very quickly - thanks!